# List from MySQL via JSON inside a parent layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, methods

I'm a beginner with android development, not even sure if I'm asking the right thing here, but here it goes.

I have an activity (that extends ListActivity) that uses JSON to generate a list based on a MySQL database. The table it produces uses a layout file as a template for producing the database on the screen.

Here's the relevant piece from the activity:

```
private void ReadDataFromDB() {

PD.show();
JsonObjectRequest jreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null,
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
try {
int success = response.getInt("success");

if (success == 1) {
JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("orders");

for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

JSONObject jobj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
item.put(ITEM_SCAN, jobj.getString(ITEM_SCAN));
item.put(ITEM_PRODUCT,
jobj.getString(ITEM_PRODUCT));

Item_List.add(item);

} // for loop ends

String[] from = { ITEM_SCAN, ITEM_PRODUCT };
int[] to = { R.id.item_scan, R.id.item_product };

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
getApplicationContext(), Item_List,
R.layout.list_items2,from, to);

setListAdapter(adapter);


PD.dismiss();

}
```

And here's the associated XML (list_items2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

<TableRow
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="New Text"
android:id="@+id/item_scan"
android:layout_column="10"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="New Text"
android:id="@+id/item_product"
android:layout_column="11"
android:textSize="30sp" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity itself has no layout (no setContentView)... I believe it uses the XML file as a template, and that's what allows it to grow as the associated MySQL table grows.

How would I put all of this inside a mother layout to keep it consistent with the rest of my activities? Would I use a FrameLayout? All my attempts have produced weird results. As it is, this code just produces a white background populated by the list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) in your case.

This is a utility class, like many others in Android. It purpose is to provide you with very easy way to create a prototype of a certain Android concept. This is an activity that knows it will be dealing with ListView and even defines a default layout. Thus, you do not need the `setContentView`.

The other thing you do here:

> adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Item_List,
>   R.layout.list_items2, **from, to**);

The adpaters are the objects that translate you objects to your listViews. The last two parameters you give are telling the Android API the correspondence between your objects and the associated view ids. Based on this Android does the mapping automatically.

After constructing this mapper (adaapter), everything is visualised after this line: `setListAdapter(adapter);`.

I have written all that, just to get you a bit better understand what happens in your code.

So what do you need to do:

- The simplest way will be if you change your `ListActivity` to [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) and you will get exactly the same functionality, but in fragment.
- Of course you will need to define an activity to hold this fragment in a `FrameLayout`, exactly as you do with all your other fragments (or, alternatively you can reuse existing activity replacing its fragment).

However, this will still leave you with less control of what you have. If, at certain point you want to change the default behaviour of the fragment, few additional steps are needed.

- Change the `ListFragment` to just Fragment (I believe you use them in all your other cases).
- Define a layout of your own for the fragment. Add a single element - `ListView` in this layout. Set this layout as content view for the fragment (now you will need that, as you do not use the utility API)
- Define an @+id for the `ListView`. Select the list view from the main code and set its adapter: `listView.setAdapter(adapter)`